# Cisco Catalyst 2950 Console to DB-9 female to USB Linux

Tags: switch, ethernet, linux

My dad has given me a secureworks iSensor with centOS, 3 ethernet cisco catalyst switches and a the wires needed to connect them. I am trying to connect several computers via ssh, and eventually a router so that I can configure my tv, ps3, etc. to the internet. Only today have I got around to connecting all of them together, and now I am attempting to configure them. I have 2 laptops with me, one dualboots fedora rawhide with windows 7, the other (on which I write) Arch Linux and linux mint. The method I am using to connect them is slightly complicated. I have a flat blue rolled cable directly into the Catalyst 2950. That wire plugs into a rollover>DB-9Female converter, which in turn, is connected to a male db-9 to usb converter. The usb converter is plugged into the fedora laptop with nothing else.
The problem:
/dev/S0
/dev/ttyS0
/dev/ttyUSB0
/dev/USB0
ttyUSB0
are not detected by putty.
dmesg |grep USB acknowledges pl2303 converter now on ttyUSB0
But no matter the combination, USB|db-9|rollover|catalyst connection at rate=9600, fails. I haven't tried hyperterminal in windows 7 because both that, and the win7 on my laptop downstairs move slower than internet explorer over tor on a dial up connection in the rain.

Comment: I personally use screen, maybe that's something for you too? In a terminal, screen /dev/ttyUSB0 9600.

Comment: Second vote for screen.

Comment: I love screen. 'cept I don't think that dodges the problem of not detecting /dev/ttyUSB0. sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB0 returns not found

Comment: I've seen Linux use other devicenames than /dev/ttyUSB0. I'd check my /dev directory for other names like /dev/tty.usbserial.

Comment: ser2net is also worth a look.

Comment: Are you running PuTTY as root when you're having problems connecting to `/dev/ttyUSB0`?  If not, please start there.

Comment: I did not run putty as root or sudo. But I didn't think that would matter as I "sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB0". And I am sure that it is on USB0 because "dmesg | grep 'USB'" returned "pl2303 adapter now on ttyUSB0". How do I move a question to a different site? I already have an account on superuser.

Comment: Furthermore, on the fedora laptop, using putty I was able to get something of a shell in cutecom and PuTTY but "show running-config" returned nothing in cutecom and "invalid marker at '^'" in putty.

Comment: And I don't think that using hyperterminal like the manual asks me to would work because I don't know windows device terminology. I don't think I even have a "COM1" port.

Comment: on the fedora box `screen /dev/ttyUSB0 9600` worked when ttyUSB0 has six hundred sixty six permissions. Too bad the question got put on hold. I would've accepted the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to this problem is simply running your terminal program as root: `sudo minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB0 -b 9600 -8`; however, there are also relatively [simple methods to access serial lines as non-root](https://askubuntu.com/a/112572) by adding your local user to the `dialout` group...  I solve this with

```
sudo adduser mpenning dialout
```

99% of Cisco consoles are happy if you use:

- 9600 baud
- 8 bits, no parity, 1 stop-bit
- No flow-control

If you use `minicom`, note that `minicom`has flow-control on by default, and would you need to manually to turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

I gave 666 permissions to /dev/ttyUSB0 and then screen /dev/ttyUSB0. Worked on the fedora laptop, not the arch one and linux mint has been corrupted so badly that it no longer boots. Besides, I like the way that screen controls better. In a way, on the fedora box, minicom, cutecom, and putty all worked w/ sudo, but screen was the only one with an understandable and readable enough interface for me to actually realize that this was the cisco console and get stuff done.